# How do I escape opening and closing brackets [] to use with cp command?

Tags: cp, escape-characters

I have a script that finds some directories and then copies their content to another directory.

now the problem is that some of the found directories need to have brackets in their naming and they look something like this:

`/directory/with/[brackets]`

and cp says that there is no such file or directory when it tries to copy it like this:

`cp -r /directory/with/[brackets]/* /some/other/directory`

Now I figured out that the brackets need to be escaped in order for this to work and I just need a simple solution for that.

Comment: You can put `"` around `filename` or `path`. Here you can use `cp -r "/directory/with/[brackets]"/* /some/other/directory`.

Comment: @davidt930 this fixed my issue thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Escape using quotes:

   ```bash
   cp -r "/directory/with/[brackets]"/* /some/other/directory
   ```

   or

   ```bash
   cp -r '/directory/with/[brackets]'/* /some/other/directory
   ```
2. Escape using backslashes:

   ```bash
   cp -r /directory/with/\[brackets\]/* /some/other/directory
   ```